# Firebase function (node.js) to return download url of image (via filename) from storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

How to write a Firebase http function that returns an url (in plain text) where an image can be downloaded?

I am using the latest version of Firebase Admin SDK.
I have a file called `images/thumbnail.png` in the default bucket for which I would like to return the URL via a HTTP call, I came up with this code:

```
exports.getImageUrl = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return firebase.storage().bucket().file("images/thumbnail.png").getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-09-2491'
  })
  .then(signedUrls => {
    return response.send(signedUrls[0])
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return response.status(500).send(error)
  })
})
```

but this fails with :

```
callback is not a function
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/src/file.js:1784:7
    at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:362:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I added logging in detail like this:

```
exports.getImage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log("start")
  const storage = firebase.storage()
  console.log(storage)
  const bucket = storage.bucket()
  console.log(bucket)
  const file = bucket.file("buildInExercises/bb_4zigzagcushionblue_thumbnail.png")
  console.log(file)
  return file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-09-2491'    
  })
  .then(urls => {
    return response.send(urls)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return response.status(500).send(error)
  })
})
```

I am now getting a proper reply:

```
{
  "message": "Permission iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob is required to perform this operation on service account projects/snookercoachapp-dev/serviceAccounts/snookercoachapp-dev@appspot.gserviceaccount.com."
}
```

It seams I have a permission issue?

Comment: Try updating to the latest version of the admin SDK.  The error is coming from inside the cloud storage SDK.

Comment: Also bear in mind that getSignedUrl currently only works if you init the admin SDK with service account credentials.

Comment: my other cloud functions work fine and I am running the latest version of the admin SDK. I think I am use the function the wrong way or something?

Comment: I dunno, try logging all over to the place to see what's happening.

Comment: in such a simple function I cannot put much logging in...

Comment: It's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Logging did not reveal anythingd.its really strange. Still thinking I am making a rookie mistake somewhere :-(

Comment: @DougStevenson by adding additional logging I am now getting a meaningful response. See the EDIT. any idea how to fix the ia.serviceAccounts.signBlob error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a symptom of the face that `getSignedUrl()` only works when you initialize the admin SDK with a service account.  This means you can't depend on the default credentials that are used when you call `admin.initializeApp()` with no arguments.

Comment: yes indeed, I figured it out. Its sad that the info is so spread around on the web. The Firebase documentation needs some work...

Comment: This actually isn't quite a Firebase issue.  The Firebase Admin SDK actually just wraps the Cloud Storage SDK, which makes it primarily a Cloud product.  The Cloud documentation discusses signed urls to some degree, but that information needs to be mapped back over to the Firebase experience.

Comment: I just got my first url back but noticed that is really really long and contains some keys in there like "GoogleAccessId" and stuff. Is this URL safe to use in public?

Comment: Yes, these URLs are meant for public consumption.  There's no private data in them.

Comment: Is it necessary to initialize admin SDK with a service account? As I am able to generate a signed url with no arguments in admin.initializeApp() but the signed url gets expired in 7 days with SignatureDoesNotMatch error. Does initializing admin SDK with a service account will solve the issue of url expiration after 7 days?